# C code Makefile,how to include path?

Tags: c, shell, makefile

I am trying to compile [bottledwater](https://github.com/confluentinc/bottledwater)

```
~/bottledwater-pg$ make
make -C ext all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/jholmes/bottledwater-pg/ext'
Package avro-c was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `avro-c.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'avro-c' found
```

Avro-c is here

```
/home/jholmes/avro-c-1.8.2
```

Makefile

```
MODULE_big = bottledwater
EXTENSION = bottledwater

AVRO_CFLAGS = $(shell pkg-config --cflags avro-c)
AVRO_LDFLAGS = $(shell pkg-config --libs avro-c)

PG_CPPFLAGS += $(AVRO_CFLAGS) -std=c99
SHLIB_LINK += $(AVRO_LDFLAGS)

OBJS = io_util.o error_policy.o logdecoder.o oid2avro.o schema_cache.o protocol.o protocol_server.o snapshot.o
DATA = bottledwater--0.1.sql

PG_CONFIG = pg_config
PGXS := $(shell $(PG_CONFIG) --pgxs)
include $(PGXS)
```

How does shell expand PG_CONFIG?
What should I do to enable main code to detect avro-c folder?
I have compiled avro-c, on Ubunutu 16.04.
My avrolib path
/`home/jholmes/avro-c-1.8.2/build/avrolib`

```
~/avro-c-1.8.2/build/avrolib$ ls
bin  include  lib
```

There is no avro-c.pc inside.
Bin content

```
/avro-c-1.8.2/build/avrolib/bin$ ls
avroappend  avrocat  avromod  avropipe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have installed the library in a non-standard location, you need to tell pkg-config about that non-standard location. The easiest way to do that, is to set the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable. You can do that when running `make`:

PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/home/jholmes/avro-c-1.8.2/lib/pkgconfig" make

This assumes that `/home/jholmes/avro-c-1.8.2/lib/pkgconfig` is where the `.pc` file resides.

Anyway, overall, I would instead recommend installing libraries in `/usr/local` instead. This should result in everything just working without manual intervention. `/usr/local` is a location used specifically for this purpose.

Comment: @Nicos C. Can you take a look at my edit?It does not work again.

Comment: @MikiBelavista Did you actually build the avro library? This should create a .pc file. See the BUILD.txt file in the avro directory for information.